# How hidden is your IP and Device ID while using Tor?

Tags: anonymity, help

So, because Reddit can decide to suspend at will, my account has been permanently suspended from the site for alleged "ban evasion"...which is a total mistake, the subreddit that they are accusing me of evading a ban on, I'm the head mod of that subreddit, so it's totally impossible for me to be evading a ban from there. They've also suspended the few alts I had (this saga started months ago, and they for some reason just suspended my main yesterday), so it appears I'm Device ID or IP banned?

Anyway, someone else on the team suggested I use Tor to continue being able to access the site. But I have a question, since I've never used Tor before.

So, I downloaded it, and made an account on an IP hider email called proton.me, and then made an account on Reddit with that account. Is that safe enough, even if I use my home wifi, and the device I primarily used?

Apologies if this seems super menial, this is just something new and I'm not sure how much it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Tor basically routes your traffic through the “Tor network”, making you appear to websites you visit as “another person”. In fact, your traffic through Tor is encrypted and forwarded to an “exit node”, which kinda makes the request for you and sends back the response through the network in the reverse way, back to you. Doing so, the IP websites see when you use Tor is your exit node's one, which is not correlated with yours. More on Tor on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(network)).

Proton does not hide your IP but just encrypts mails as described [here](https://proton.me/blog/encrypted-email), and claims not to log data from its customers. Anyway, Reddit has no means to access your IP via your mail provider other than a lawsuit (which is unlikely), or by adding trackers to mails. Trackers are probably present for advertising purpose, but I don't think the company would use the IP associated with trackers to ban someone.

Using the Wi-Fi isn't a problem for your IP when using Tor, as described above. Your device ID and stuff could be used to target you, even [fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint), but in a basic case like yours, an IP hide should be sufficient (in my opinion) as ban is usually done by IP address.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long-term problem of scum service detection, IMHO. Any service can *easily* deploy an onion entrance to itself, it will **not** alter the security protocols: clearnet addresses and LAN ones are the sources of the threats of the **exact** same severity and importance. Even a Facebook has it's own official Tor entrance, that's an indicator - just FYI...

Answer (score 0):

Quick correction only re

> [Proton] claims not to log data from its customers.

It claims otherwise, declaring so, for more than a year, e.g. [ProtonMail criticized for handing activist's IP address to authorities, leading to their arrest](https://www.techspot.com/news/91126-protonmail-criticized-handing-activist-ip-address-authorities-leading.html)

```
The company says it is obliged to obey Swiss laws
By Rob Thubron September 7, 2021 at 5:17 AM
```